# How to set the stored value in a buildForm Entity function (symfony2)

Tags: symfony

I have this code in an Entity used via ArrayCollection:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('imageFile',VichImageType::class, array(
            'label' => false,
            'required'      => false,
            'allow_delete'  => true, // not mandatory, default is true
            'download_link' => true, // not mandatory, default is true
        ));
        $builder->add('weight','hidden',array(
            'attr' => array(
                //'value' =>'__name__',
                'class' => 'weight'
            )
        ));
    }
```

When the buildForm is called for a "new Action" I want that the "default value" is set to "**name**". But if I decomment the line

```
//'value' =>'__name__',
```

this setting is made for the "edit action" too.

How can I access to the "stored" value of this "entry" to check If I'm in a "new action" or in a "edit Action" ?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to set default value for entity/document is in entity class:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string")
 */
protected $weight = 'name';
```

But `empty_data` should work in form builder:

```
$builder->add('weight','hidden',array(
        'empty_data' => 'name',
        'attr' => array(
            'class' => 'weight'
        )
    ));
```

Answer (score 0):

> How can I access to the "stored" value of this "entry" to check If I'm
>   in a "new action" or in a "edit Action" ?

**You should have separates actions to know what is the exactly context.**

Otherwise you can use form model data to examine id property of the entity to get the context of the action. Then you can modify form with form events.

**References:**

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html
http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/form/form_events.html

Answer (score 0):

u can set default value by

```
  ->add('myfield', 'text', array(
  'label' => 'Field',
  'data' => 'Default value'
  ))
```

and

```
 ->add('myfield', 'text', array(
 'label' => 'Field',
 'choices' => array()
```

))
to pass an array (ex for dropdowns)
, all the best